# VideoFram frame to byte array

Tags: arrays, data-conversion, ant-media-server-sdk

I'm using the Ant Media SDK to develop a webRTC capable app. The thing is that I need to send some frames every 300 ms to a recognition service. I have found that there's a listener that pass the frames:

```java
 surfaceTextureHelper.startListening((VideoFrame frame) -> {
//some code
}
```

The thing is, how can I get a byte[] from that frame, in Camera1API you had setPreviewCallback and received directly a byte[] with the frame. How can I make the same conversion??

Thanks in advance